# What is happening during this flashback scene from The Evil Within?

Tags: video-games, the-evil-within

In Sebastian's flashback he sees Valério scratching his head and and imagining himself...

Where does this image in his head come from?

Also he disappears then he reappears as a haunted?

Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is simply a STEM-induced flashback which depicts Valerio turning into a Haunted. So the actual timeline is not that Valerio disappears and reappears as a Haunted, but instead that Valerio turns into a Haunted, Sebastian kills Valerio, and then Sebastian has a flashback which shows Valerio's transformation into a Haunted.  You will notice that the part of Valerio's scalp that he was scratching in the flashback is bloody when he turns to kill Sebastian indicating that the "itchy" flashback events takes place before the fight between Sebastian and Valerio.

From [The Evil Within wiki page on Valerio](https://theevilwithin.fandom.com/wiki/Valerio_Jimenez):

> Sebastian frantically puts down the abberant doctor in self-defense,
> Marcelo in utter disbelief.
>
> Afterwards, Sebastian experiences another STEM headache and a
> flashback of Valerio's transformation into a Haunted appears; Valerio
> is seen screaming maniacally about an 'itch' located on his left
> temple, which he madly scratches open in desperation. Valerio is seen
> with red veins all over his body like other Haunted and begins
> mutilating a portion of his scalp as he fades away.

Comment: But he disappears on the flashback ,he comes back as a haunted?Then Sebastian kills the haunted Valério ? is that correct?

Comment: I believe that Valerio's disappearance at 1:25 in your video is just showing that Sebastian's flashback is ending and not that Valerio actually disappeared at that point in time.  And then, yes, sometime afterwards Sebastian kills Valerio.

Comment: He clearly fades away.To where?

Comment: The entire flashback (from fade in at 1:01 to fade out at 1:25) is hallucination in the mind of Sebastian caused by the STEM.  So at 1:25 the Valerio hallucination really doesn't fade out to a physical location but instead fades out of the consciousness of Sebastian.

Comment: But he kills the haunted Valério right?

Comment: Yes, but remember that 1:01 - 1:25 is a _flashback_ that happens an undetermined amount of time _before_ haunted Velario is killed at 0:46.  So if you were to re-edit the video in the _real_ chronological order, the part from 1:01 - 1:25 happens first, then 0:00 - 1:01 happens next (sometime later), and then 1:25 - 3:00 happens last.

Comment: How Valério is in Sebastian’s conscioness?

Comment: According to the wiki page, it is "another STEM headache and a flashback".  The STEM can cause people to have headaches and hallucinations.

If I have answered your question, please feel free to accept my answer above.